# Jest fails for same string

Tags: node.js, string, jestjs, buffer

I'm trying unit testing for the first time with Jest on a personal project, and some of my tests failed even though the data received was the exact same as expected, here's an example:

```
test("decrypt method works correctly", () =>{
    const myAES = new rijndael("", "0bdfa595235c307a105d593fb78fbb13", { key: "SOME 128 BIT KEY", bits: 128, rounds: 9 })
    expect(myAES.decrypt()).toStrictEqual({
        "c": "0bdfa595235c307a105d593fb78fbb13",
        "p": "ATTACK AT DAWN!",
        "errors": []
    })
}
```

[image: Jest report]

So then I tried to check if it's a problem with Jest or my code:

```
const r = myAES.decrypt()
console.log(typeof r.p) // string
console.log(r.p === "ATTACK AT DAWN!") // false
```

Which just made me even more confused as the strings look the same. The code that I'm testing is an AES encryption function (Don't worry it's just a personal project for fun won't be used in production) that processes text as nodeJS [Buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), and in the end uses the [toString()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method to convert it back to a string. I'm thinking that may be why I'm having issues, but can't seem to find exactly why. Would love it if someone could point me in the right direction so I can get rid of this error. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'll save everyone the pain of reading my AES implementation for now as I don't think it's a problem with the encryption but let me know if that's necessary

Comment: Not sure that the 'p' element is the error, have you checked the full structure, as strictEquals means everything has to match.

Comment: Can you convert both to hex and see if there is any difference between the two. Use can use this example to dump string to hex `<string>.split('').reduce((h,c)=>h+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2,'0'),'')`

Comment: Oh right I should have thought of that! I'll give that a go, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so turns out it was a stupid mistake where I overlooked the series of null bytes that tend to end up in the end of the buffer after decryption. While toString() will turn the buffer into the string I want the computer will not recognise it as the same string. So all I had to do was strip the null bytes that follow. Assuming that the null bytes should only appear at the end of the string as they normally do:

```
const i = buffer.indexOf(0x00)
const result = buffer.slice(0, i).toString() //solves the problem
```